# Laravel DomPDF Getting Blank File When Using Axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf, Axios and Vuejs to generate PDF files. Yes, I can download the file, but the file is blank and the size of file is 0 bytes. Why does this happens?

**Controller**

```
public function downloadPDF()
{
    $staffs = Staff::all();
    $pdf = PDF::loadview('staffs.pdf', ['staffs' => $staffs]);
    return $pdf->output();
}
```

**PDF View**

```
<table class='table table-bordered'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @php $i=1 @endphp
        @foreach ($staffs as $staff)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $i++ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $staff->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $staff->email }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('staff-management/download-pdf', [StaffController::class, 'downloadPDF'])->name('staff.pdf');
```

**View**

```
exportFiles() {
  this.loading = true;
  if ($('.export-files').val() == 'PDF') {
    this.axios
      .get('api/staff/staff-management/download-pdf', {
        responseType: 'blob',
        Accept: 'application/pdf',
      })
      .then((response) => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'}));
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        console.log(link);
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', 'staffs.pdf'); //or any other extension
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.loading = false;
      });
  }
},
```

Comment: i am not sure about vuejs but this axios works axios({
        url: 'http://localhost:8002/test',
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'blob',
    }).then((response) => {
        var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
        var fileLink = document.createElement('a');

        fileLink.href = fileURL;
        fileLink.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf');
        document.body.appendChild(fileLink);

        fileLink.click();
    });

Comment: @JohnLobo: Still not working. FYI, when I test my url in Postman (api/staff/staff-management/download-pdf), it shows blank. I dont know why. But, if I use pure laravel, above code is working.

Comment: Now, I've found the problem. The file can't be authenticated. If I leave it free, it can be downloaded by anyone. But if I authenticate the file with middleware and ```Auth::user()->token()``` the file shows blank. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `axios` treats every response received from server as `blob` and pdf is created using JavaScript .To avoid that while sending response in server send status too. For example

```
 return [
        'status'=>"success",
        "data"=> mb_convert_encoding($pdf->output(), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8')
    ];
```

and then in axios

```
exportFiles() {
        this.loading = true;
        if ($('.export-files').val() == 'PDF') {
            this.axios
                .get('api/staff/staff-management/download-pdf', {
                  
                    Accept: 'application/pdf',
                })
                .then((response) => {

                    if(response.data.status=="success") {
                        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data.data], {type: 'application/pdf'}));
                        const link = document.createElement('a');
                        console.log(link);
                        link.href = url;
                        link.setAttribute('download', 'staffs.pdf'); //or any other extension
                        document.body.appendChild(link);
                        link.click();
                    } else{
                        alert("Not Authenticated");
                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    this.loading = false;
                });
        }
    },
```

Other way is send status from server other than 200 if user is not authenticated.so you can handle it in axios error handling

Another way first check user is logged in if not dont show download pdf button .

Comment: No, it's not. The real problem is this https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/120444801?noredirect=1. But, thanks anyway.